# Electron dialog.showOpenDialog() Filters not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm working on a fork of an IDE on GitHub and one of the main issues were that it saved the files to cookies, instead of the common computer. So, I needed a way to save and open files. I've gotten the saving file system down by using blobs. However, with the opening file, according to the console, provides an "Unexpected String," even though it's pretty vanilla.

Below is the function:

```
function openFileCMD() {
console.log('Opening File...');
dialog.showOpenDialog( (fileName), {
    filters: [{ 
        name: 'Text Files', 
        extensions: ['txt'] 
    }, { 
        name: 'HTML Files',
        extensions: ['html', 'htm']
    }, {
        name: 'Rich Text File',
        extensions: ['rtf'] 
    }, { 
        name: 'XML/YAMLFile', 
        extensions: ['xml', 'yml', 'yaml'] 
    }, { 
        name: 'JSON File', 
        extensions: ['json'] }
    ]} => {
    if(fileName === undefined) {
        console.log("Ouch. That wall hurt. Can you pick a file this time? Please?");
        // document.getElementsByClassName('alert')[0].style.display = "block";
        return;
    }
    fs.readFile(fileName[0], 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            alert("Woah. Something went wrong. Check the console for more info.");
            console.log("An error occured reading the file : " + err.message);
            return;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("code-editor").value = "<pre><code>" + data + "</code></pre>";
        }
    });
closeSidebar();
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can either help fix this or point me in the right direction to resolving this! :)

Edit: I have tried with `dialog.showOpenDialog` all on one line: still to no avail.

Comment: Did you double check the Electron API reference? That could help.

Comment: @WillHoskings Yeah, I virtually copied it at first and then just changed the existing filters and added a few new ones. I wouldn't really imagine that it would break just from that.

Comment: This has nothing to do with this, but you should cache the `document.get*` calls.
Could you throw us a stack trace in hastebin?

Comment: @WillHoskings I know what you mean by to cache the `document.get*`s, but wdym by a stack trace in Hastebin: I've never used the service before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Unexpected String," error message you get is not related to the filters, but to the fact that [dialog.showOpenDialog](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/dialog#dialogshowopendialogbrowserwindow-options-callback) is not called properly...

```
dialog.showOpenDialog (filename, options => { ... });
```

should be instead:

```
dialog.showOpenDialog (options, filename => { ... });
```

Comment: Ah, I see now. I just needed to flip the "fileName" variable to end of the filters. Thanks, @Mikaeru!!